# I can't add a Indicator Applet to Panel in Gnome-Classic

Tags: indicator, gnome-classic

ubuntu 11.10

I recently changed unity for classic Desktop. So, i noticed that the volume control dissappeared.

So i read everywhere that the only thing to do is add the Inidicator Applet in the panel. But i dont have that option in my applet list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indicator applet has not been ported to GNOME 3 and GTK3 yet.  This is required for it to work in Ubuntu 11.10.  There is currenly a [bug tracking it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+bug/724369).

Comment: In 12.04, it is used by default in gnome-session-fallback, and it's working well.

Answer (score 27):

### Indicator-Applet

Indicator-applet is now available for testing in a PPA.

*As with all PPAs - these are for testing purposes.  Have a stable backup or use ppa-purge to remove PPAs that could make your system unstable.*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install the applet you want to add to the panel:

1) The whole indicator applet:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

[image]

2) Unity Global Menu type applet:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-appmenu
```

[image]

3) Session applet:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-session
```

[image]

4) Standard applet:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet
```

[image]

To add to the panel:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right click the panel if using Gnome-Classic or
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right click the panel if using Gnome-Classic (No Effects)

Choose Add To Panel and add the following indicator

[image]

You can tidy up by removing the old notification area.

The end-result could look like this:

[image]

N.B. I've also added RadioTray, StackApplet and Skype...

Comment: Thanks, great answer that worked like a charm on my Ubuntu 11.10 system. (The Ubuntu documentation seriously needs some updating with information like this - i.e. how to migrate to the new world and discuss all the "features" that used to be there but are no longer there "out of the box".)

Comment: Addendum : if at the "sudo apt-get install indicator*" stage you get asked to accept an end user licence, it is the TAB key that will move focus to the <OK> so you can accept it with ENTER. (just hitting Enter or space wont help!)

Comment: Thanks, works for 16.04 as well. The `Alt`+`Win`+`Right Click` trick is... well... tricky :)