# How to edit whitelisted apps in the notification area in gnome fallback session?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel, notification-area, gnome-session

In order to edit which whitelisted apps are visible in the notification area, I normally could use dconf editor and edit from the unity panel entry [as shown here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html).

The thing is, I have gnome fallback installed only, so the unity panel entry is obviously not present in dconf

So how can i edit the notification area, in order to remove the second battery icon that is visible?

Thanks for your help

(EDIT) here is a pic of what i need to remove, its the first battery icon, which is in the notification applet, not the indicator applet

[image: panel]

Comment: If you use the indicator-applet, I would assume that whitelisting will be the same as for Natty... http://askubuntu.com/questions/69377/i-cant-add-a-indicator-applet-to-panel-in-gnome-classic/72764#72764

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the issue is with the notification applet and not the indicator applet, thats why i have two battery icons, one in the indicator space, which is fine, and one in the notification applet which i want to get rid of

Comment: are you sure you havent just added the second battery applet?  Try either WIN+ALT and right-click or ALT+right click over the battery icon and remove the applet.

Comment: no, its definitely in the notification applet

Comment: if you've installed the inidicator applet, why do you need the gnome notification area - surely just deleting this will resolve your issue?

Comment: not really, the redshiftgui and jupiter icons are only visible as part of the notification applet. if i remove the notification applet, then i loose  control of both of those

Comment: @Jayo both have indicator applet support. You need to log out and login. You may also need to change some option somewhere (depends on if the applications have those settings - but that would be something for another question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, what you are trying to achieve is not possible. This is caused by a bug, which will be a bit difficult to solve, due to some changes in GNOME3.

- There is not longer a separate `gnome-power-manager` process. It's now a plugin of `gnome-settings-daemon`.
- If you disable the plugin, you will lose power management.
- If you use another power manager, such as `xfce4-power-manager`, you will not get the indicator (which you want).
- There is no system tray whitelist in GNOME Classic.

All in all, there is no direct solution, and your best bet is to wait until the bug is solved.

---

### How to use xfce4-power-manager instead of GNOME Power Manager (the plugin) in GNOME 3

This will show you how to disable GNOME Power Manager in GNOME 3, and then how to enable xfce4-power-manager.

- Install `dconf-editor`.
- Navigate to `org.gnome.setting-daemon.plugins.power` and untick the active option.
  [image]
- Install xfce4-power-manager (`sudo apt-get install xfce4-power-manager`).
- Add this to your start up applications.
- Log out and log back in.
- You should now see a single battery icon, which will be provided by xfce4-power-manager.

Comment: if that is the case, is there any way to have the redshift and jupiter icon be visible in the indicator applet rather than the notification applet? (i recall when installing the radiotray app that it asks on first run where would i like the icon to be placed, so must be possible right?)

Comment: or if it isn't at all possible, how would i go about replacing the gnome power manager with the xfce power manager (which actually seems to have more control than the gnome manager funny enough)

Comment: @Jayo I believe Jupiter and Redshift have indicators; you just need to remove the notification applet (I think) to get them to show. As for the xfce4-power-manager question - I'll have to update my answer (not right now, but I will do it soon, if you don't mind).

Comment: not at all, of course i dont mind, any help is appreciated. its redshiftgui (a fork) im using rather than redshift, either way i had to enable the notification applet to get to see them to begin with, maybe its because in using gnome-fallback?

Comment: @Jayo most likely. I may have to do some testing manually to see if I can get them to show up, and then I will tell you the steps.

Comment: @Jayo does my update solve it for you now?

Comment: you sir are a gentleman and a scholar! yes it works perfectly, and funny enough i now have a lot more control in my power management, so nice bonus :) thanks again Roland, awesome

Comment: @Jayo: you're welcome, and thanks for the kind words :D!

Answer (score 2):

I have one solution with this `ppa:jconti/gnome3`.

It is simple, modify *gnome-settings-daemon* to hide the battery icon (like in unity) :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
gedit patch_gnome-fallback.patch
```

Copy that in the `patch_gnome-fallback.patch` file:

```
--- gsd-power-manager.c 2012-02-05 21:27:41.000000000 +0100
+++ ../../gnome-settings-daemon-3.2.2/plugins/power/gsd-power-manager.c 2012-02-05 20:20:36.000000000 +0100
@@ -646,8 +646,7 @@
         if (manager->priv->previous_icon == NULL) {

                 /* set fallback icon */
-                if (g_strcmp0 (g_getenv ("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"), "Unity") != 0)
-                        gtk_status_icon_set_visible (manager->priv->status_icon, TRUE);
+                gtk_status_icon_set_visible (manager->priv->status_icon, FALSE);
                 gtk_status_icon_set_from_gicon (manager->priv->status_icon, icon);
                 manager->priv->previous_icon = icon;
                 return TRUE;
```

Then run these commands:

```
apt-get source gnome-settings-daemon
cd gnome-settings-daemon-*/plugins/power
patch < ../../../patch_gnome-fallback.patch
cd ../..
debchange -i
```

[Tape some comments]

```
debuild -us -uc -i -I
```

And for the installation:

```
sudo debi
```

Restart and it works (if you have install *indicator-power* package).

*Thanks to quantenemitter for the todo with another package https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopnova/+bug/844983/comments/8*

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove the indicator and leave the notification icon:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-power
```

The indicator is more full-featured than the battery icon (which doesn't really do anything) but at least you'll only have one battery icon.