# In there an indicator applet for Gnome Panel 3?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, indicator, gnome-panel, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't add a Indicator Applet to Panel in Gnome-Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69377/i-cant-add-a-indicator-applet-to-panel-in-gnome-classic)

I've been exploring Gnome Panel 3 in 11.10 for a while now, and I think it's really great. However, I would really like to use indicators the same way as it's used in 10.04. Is that possible yet, and if so, how do I do it?