# How can I get back the Sound-Menu integration for music players in Gnome classic?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, indicator-sound

I have just upgraded to oneiric (11.10) from natty.

In Unity-2D sessions, the sound-menu integration lets me control Banshee (and maybe Clementine too).

In Gnome Classic sessions however, it's gone. Is there a way to get it back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in 11.10, gnome-classic uses the standard Gnome-Applets.  Unity and Unity-2D uses the *indicator-applet*.

Note - in 12.04, the indicator-applet is installed by default when installing gnome-classic.

You should install the indicator-applet as per the [linked Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/72764/14356) - the same sound indicator should then be available for you to use.

[image]