# No volume control in "Gnome Classic" sessions

Tags: 11.10, sound, panel

I've just installed Oneiric (64-bit), and immediately after installation I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic) to get the Gnome Classic interface (I've tried Unity... I really wanted to like it, but it just never stuck). It seemed to go ok, but when I'm in a Gnome Classic session, I have no volume control applet, and there doesn't appear to be one in the Add To Panel list.

The volume control is there when I'm in a Unity session with the same user. This may be similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89680/lost-volume-control) question, but the circumstances seemed different enough to warrant a new question.

Comment: if you add the indicator-applet PPA and add this to the panel - do you have the sound applet backup? http://askubuntu.com/a/72764/14356

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks, for some reason that didn't come up in my searches. That did it. If I remember, I'll upvote your answer there when I get 4 more reputation, heh.

Comment: I guess this can be marked as effectively a duplicate of that other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to [add indicator-applet to the panel](https://askubuntu.com/a/72764/14356).

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and enter

```
alsamixer
```

That's the console volume control.
Alternatively, start the pulseaudio-daemon:

```
open /usr/bin/pulseaudio
```

but in classic mode, it doesn't work when you have more than one device (2nd device not showing in classic mode eihter).