# gnome panel broken since last update

Tags: 14.04, gnome-classic

With Ubuntu 14.04, I happily used `gnome-session-fallback` until yesterday, when a regular update broke my top bar panel after reboot. I now have access to the shortcuts I added, but the "system" icons are gone:

[image]

I have no more the symbol (?) giving access to logout, restart, system, ... The clock, sound icon, network manager, language,.. have also disappeared (see this example panel:)

[image]

I tried **really** lots of things, including reinstalling with `apt-get --reinstall install`, switching to mate (was the same !), returning to `gnome-session-fallback`, trying out `gnome-shell` whith lightgdm, removing it...

I'm just stuck with my partial top panel ! My system seems to work, but I'm afraid there some inconsistencies left...

More info:

- Both `$DESKTOP_SESSION` and `$GDMSESSION` are set to `gnome-fallback-compiz`
- `wmctrl -m` tells me:

out:

```
Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

Any clues of the following steps I can take ? At present, can't shutdown from the GUI, I need to enter `shutdown now` in terminal.

Comment: Okay, so I thought I respected http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask and http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask but apparently some user doesn't agree, and downvoted (ok with that), but a comment explaining why would have been helpful so we don't all waste our time...

Comment: Some people voted to close your question, because they think, it should be reported as a bug on the official  bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks @David Foerster for that clarification, I disagree because this might happen to other people using the `gnome-classic-fallback`, and I have added an answer giving a fix. But, ... we'll see.

Comment: **To close voters:** please consider [Are bug reports suitable for this site?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/226/175814)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to reset your session. Delete any cached configuration in your $HOME folder, within the dot folders (.config, .gnome).
Afterwards, you would need to reallocate your icons and applets.

Comment: I might try, but this will break for sure lots of personal setting so I'd rather use some "automated" procedure.

Comment: @kebs: You can move the current configuration files to a backup location and see, whether that leads to improvement. A good set of relevant files is listed in https://askubuntu.com/a/56314/175814.

Comment: The things is: I don't want to loose my current ability to login using my session: I tried adding a test user (with `adduser`) and login fails with that user (I get back to the "login" screen after 5 sec.).

Comment: Just by creating a user with "adduser" does not allow you to login. You need to create its home and copy in the skeleton files (/etc/skel).
On the other side, you don't risk the ability to log in into your session.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem after some time, answering own question for future readers:

What I was missing in my panel is named an **indicator-applet** (see [packages here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=indicator-applet) ).

Once I made sure it was correctly reinstalled (with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install indicator-applet-complete`), I just edited my panel (Win+Alt+right-click) and added the applet, as explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/72764/69802).

Now, only need to fix the position in the panel, buts thats a minor problem.