# 16.04 Flashback Metacity: ALL upper-right applets now missing

Tags: 16.04, gnome-panel

I'm on 16.04. 3 Monitors. NVidia card. Station has been upgraded from 14.04. I'm using the Flashback metacity theme.

There are a lot of people experiencing this issue in these forums [ which I've scoured ]. The solutions I've tried. They do not work.

All was well until 2 days ago. Time/date logout gear thing -- all upper right items gone.

I've tried the following:

1. reinstall indicator-datetime
2. rm -rf ~/.config/dconf/
3. Reinstall flashback
4. sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
5. dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/
6. pkill -f datetime
7. Reboot, logout, login ...etc.
8. Settings -> show date ..etc.

No change whatsoever. Sound/Volume is missing --all applets in upper right are missing and right-clicking does not offer any options.

```
ps ax | grep -i indicator-datetime
```

For the time being I'm running xclock. But have no logout,restart,sound ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

[I can't add a Indicator Applet to Panel in Gnome-Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69377/i-cant-add-a-indicator-applet-to-panel-in-gnome-classic)

Was able to manually add back in equivalent items as detailed above. Still wondering why all that stuff disappeared.